# My app in the appstore does not seen in notification center settings

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, notifications

I have a problem with some devices.My app is at the app store but some users say that my app does not seen in the notification center settings.I checked log files and I saw that my app got device token in the didRegisterForRemoteNoticationsWithDeviceToken method.Although i can get device token why my app not seen in the notification center settings.

Comment: when you create profile you have to enable push notification service. u have do it ?

Comment: Yes i have do it Already some users can get push notification on their devices